# How to enforce input in one to many relation between two business objects in XAF

Tags: vb.net, xaf

I have a Bill and PR classes with one to many relation between them (one Bill to many PR), how can I enforce input of PR class based on Amount property in Bill class?
only if **Amount >= FIXED_AMOUNT** then enforce the entering of PR details, otherwise do not such thing .

```
<DefaultClassOptions()> _
Public Class Bill Inherits BaseObject
Public Sub New(ByVal session As Session)
        MyBase.New(session)
    End Sub 
    Public Overrides Sub AfterConstruction()
        MyBase.AfterConstruction()
    End Sub
    Private _Amount As Decimal
    Public Property Amount() As Decimal
        Get
         Return _Amount
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _Amount = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _PR As PR
    <Association("PR-Bill")>
    Public Property PR As PR
        Get
            Return _PR
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As PR)
            SetPropertyValue("PR", _PR, value)
        End Set
    End Property    
End Class

<DefaultClassOptions()> _
Public Class PR Inherits BaseObject
Public Sub New(ByVal session As Session)
        MyBase.New(session)
    End Sub
     Public Overrides Sub AfterConstruction()
        MyBase.AfterConstruction()
        End Sub
        Private _Name As String
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Association("PR-Bill")>
    Public ReadOnly Property Bill() As XPCollection(Of Bill)
        Get
            Return GetCollection(Of Bill)("Bill")
        End Get
    End Property    
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

using DevExpress.Persistent.Validation

something like

```
[NotMapped, Browsable(false),
RuleFromBoolProperty("NeedsInputRule", DefaultContexts.Save,"You need to input PR ", UsedProperties = "Amount")]

public bool NeedsInput => Amount >= Fixed_Amount;
```